# How to fill in ggplot shapefile map using a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I am trying to fill a US map where each state is filled in by mean salary (In the default colour scale). I have the shapefile, and a dataframe which looks like this (Data falsified):

```
data <- structure(list(State = c("Arkansas",
                           "Iowa",
                           "California",
                           "Idaho"),
                 MeanSalary = c(50000,60000,62000,55000)),
                 row.names=1:4, class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)

map <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "usamap")

PlotData <- merge(map, data, by = "State")
```

This all works so far. I can also make an empty map:

```
map_base <- ggplot(data = PlotData, mapping=(aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)
map_base
```

However, I can't fill in the map with the values.

```
map_base <- ggplot(data = PlotData, mapping=(aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = PlotData$MeanSalary)
map_base
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2834334): fill
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here I provided two solutions to plot polygons using `ggplot2`.

**Solution 1: geom_sf**

`sf` class is the next generation spatial data class in R. `geom_sf` can plot the `sf` object. To do this, we need to convert the `sp` object to `sf` object. Here I used the state spatial polygons from the `USAboundaries` package as an example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(USAboundaries)

# Get the state data
state <- us_states()

# Check the class
class(state)
# [1] "sf"         "data.frame"

# Create example data frame
data <- structure(list(State = c("Arkansas",
                                 "Iowa",
                                 "California",
                                 "Idaho"),
                       MeanSalary = c(50000,60000,62000,55000)),
                  row.names=1:4, class = "data.frame")

# Merge data to state and filter for these records
state_filter <- state %>% 
  left_join(data, by = c("name" = "State")) %>%
  # Remove Hawaii, Alaska, and Puerto Rico to just focus on the rest states
  filter(!name %in% c("Hawaii", "Alaska", "Puerto Rico"))

# Plot the data
ggplot(state_filter) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = MeanSalary))
```

[image]

**Solution 2: ggspatial package**

The `ggspatial package` can plot the `sp` object. So if you don't want to work with `sf` object, using `ggspatial` could be an option.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(USAboundaries)
library(sp)
library(ggspatial)

# Convert the sf object to sp object
state_filter_sp <- as(state_filter, "Spatial")

# Plot the data
ggplot() +
  annotation_spatial(state_filter_sp) +
  layer_spatial(state_filter_sp, aes(fill = MeanSalary))
```

[image]